# MFC Scroll Bar in a Nested Subbox

Tags: c++, mfc, cwnd

I have a CWnd based MySubBox class. I would like to display the Scrollbar if MySubBox child contents exceed the window size. I already used WM_VSCROLL, WM_HSCROLL, WM_SIZE to handle scrolling. I have a case where I have a Nested Subboxes.
Example - Assume I have a Nested Subbox. A is the Parent Subbox, B is the Child Subbox, C is the Grandchild Subbox. C Subbox is bigger because of its contents. How can I display Scrollbar in C Subbox only ignoring A & B Subbox

Comment: You're probably looking for [`CScrollView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class). The example (as I understand it) reads a bit disturbing: If you find that you need to host a scrollable view inside another scrollable view, you've just reinvented the horrifying UX that is The Web at large.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I want to have a Scrollable View inside another Scrollable View. Does CScrollView help to achieve a Nested Scrollable View? Or else is it too difficult to implement it?